# check if any character of a string is inside a list

Tags: python, string, list, if-statement, compare

This is a Pig latin game and it works but right now if I input any of the characters defined by the variable "special" I get it returned as True but if I add another character it returns as false.

---

So it's only checking if the whole string and not any character of the string.
I want that if I input "Ban/", it gets returned as invalid. So if any of the characters defined in "special" are found in "word" I want it to return true.

```
special = list('[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]')
word=input("\nType in a word : ")
if word in special:
    print("Your entry is not valid.")
else:
    pigLatin()
```

i also tried this before but it's essentially the same

```
if word[0:] in special:
```

Here's the [full snipet](https://onlinegdb.com/r1fuyWHEV) if it helps. Condition is in Line:41

Beware I started a few days ago so it may look really messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through each character in the input and perform the check one by one. You can do this with `any()` and a generator comprehension:

```
if any(i in special for i in word):
    print("Your entry is not valid.")
```

You may also consider using `sets` by checking if the intersection between `word` and `special` isn't empty:

```
if set(word) & set(special):
    print("Your entry is not valid.")
```

Comment: what does sets do? I understand loops but if you could give me a clarification on sets I would be most thankful

Comment: @senpai_bot a `set` is an unordered collection of unique elements. One example of a `set` operation is `&`, which calculates the intersection of two different sets (all elements that are in both sets). `set(word) & set(special)` computes the intersection of word and special to check if there are common elements. If there is a common element, then the resultant set is considered "True" by python, which sets off the if statement. It's just another way of checking.